# HTML get textfield and checkbox content/value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic3

I got a little problem with my HTML, i can't get datas from HTML to TS.
I would like to save all the document and send it to my DB.
I got something like (HTML):

```
  <h3>Part 1 : General Information</h3>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime displayFormat="MMM DD YYYY" [(ngModel)]="date"></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked>First Name</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" aria-placeholder="First Name" placeholder="First Name"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked>Last Name</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" aria-placeholder="Last Name" placeholder="Last Name"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Birthdate</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime displayFormat="MMM DD YYYY" [(ngModel)]="birthdate"></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>
```

I get this datas onSave and push it into a List like this (TS):

```
public key: string = 'Save1';
public save: string[] = new Array();
public checkedValue = document.querySelector('.medical-form');
saveQuestionnaire(){
  for ( var _isave in this._symptoms ) {
      this.save.push(this.symptoms[_isave]);
      console.log("Number of symptom (27)");
  }
  console.log('TEST QUERY SELECTOR', this.checkedValue);
  console.log("this.save",this.save)
  this._storage.set(this.key,this.save);
  this.save = null;
}
```

I don't know how i could get this infos. Should i use a $scope ?

Thanks for your time and your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use ngModel and variable in the scope of .ts file, like:

```html
<ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked>First Name</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" aria-placeholder="First Name" placeholder="First Name" [(ngModel)]="firstName" name="firstName"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked>Last Name</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" aria-placeholder="Last Name" placeholder="Last Name" [(ngModel)]="lastName" name="lastName">           </ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

And you should set variables in the scope of class:

```js
public firstName: string = "";
public lastName: string = "";
console.log(this.firstName);
```

Comment: I have to put everywhere parameter like [(ngModel)] ? Thanks for your reply

Comment: For ion-input tags the basic way is the way to use [(ngModel) and the name attribute its also important, for more doubt of components think you can read the ionic API Documentation for example: 

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/checkbox/Checkbox